# Collection View Batch Update Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I intermittently get `Crashlytics` reports with the following error:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000e
 raw

libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_msgSend + 5
1
UIKit   
-[UICollectionViewUpdate _computeItemUpdates] + 1588
2
UIKit   
-[UICollectionViewUpdate initWithCollectionView:updateItems:oldModel:newModel:oldVisibleBounds:newVisibleBounds:] + 254
3
UIKit   
-[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations] + 6904
4
UIKit   
-[UICollectionView performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 386
```

How can I debug this? The crash appears to be internal to a `UICollectionView`. Does this mean the crash is internal to an Apple SDK?

Comment: Might be interesting to see the blocks passed to performBatchUpdates

Comment: I've noticed crashes here when attempting to do add and move two items into the same spot. There appears to be actual memory corruption happening here.  If it doesn't crash here it will crash later.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a symbolic breakpoint with `-[UICollectionViewUpdate _computeItemUpdates]` as the value. Whenever that method is called, you'll be able to navigate the stack trace and (hopefully) see which line of your code is the last to be called before the crash.

The downside of this approach is you'll probably get a lot of pauses that are not followed by the crash, but it'll give you an idea of where it's coming from. Once you find the source of the crash in your code, unset the breakpoint and change a value or set something related to the cells until you can cause the crash to happen.

This is generally my approach to tracking down crashes from my crash reports from Flurry. Being you've ask this question half a year ago, if you found a solution to tracking down these types of bugs, I would appreciate it if you shared :)